# drupal 7 nodes listed in views are not attached to the menu, but need to be

Tags: menu, drupal-7, view

Using Drupal 7, I am displaying news articles via a View. The view is linked into the menu, naturally, but as a consequence the news articles are not. This becomes an issue because when an article's detail page is displayed, the site loses the active trail and consequently the breadcrumb trail and the left-hand secondary navigation menu lose their place. 

Is there some way of setting the menu to think it's in a certain place within the menu tree, eg. Your College -> Life at the College -> News & Events? 
I've seen menu_tree_set_path, which looks promising, but haven't seen an example of how it's used (at least in terms an Enthusiastic Amateur like myself would get). 

As ever, any and all assistance given is greatly appreciated,
~Matt

Answer (score 0):

The Context module will allow you to set the active trail of a drupal menu dependant on paths etc.

https://drupal.org/project/context

Answer (score 0):

When you're dealing with breadcrumbs, an easy way to achieve breadcrumbs on a per content type basis (and others) is the [custom_breadcrumbs](https://drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs) module.

On a separate note, if you want to display full menus, look at the [menu_block](https://drupal.org/project/menu_block) module.  We used this plus the menu_tree_set_path() function to display local menus on nodes that weren't in menus.

```
$config = menu_block_get_config(1); 
$path = "node/{$nid}";
menu_tree_set_path($config['menu_name'], $path);
$data = menu_tree_build($config);
```

The number passed to menu_block_get_config(), is the delta of the menu_block configuration in blocks.

With $data you can use a drupal_render or pass it back to another theme rendering function.